# Newtonsoft.Json.Linq not .Net Standard 2.0?

Tags: json.net, .net-standard

Microsoft's API Portability tester is telling me that classes in Newtonsoft.Json.Linq are note supported in .Net Standard (any version). Is this true or is it a false positive?

[image]

Comment: just created a simple .net standard project and JObject.Parse works as expected.

Comment: @BohdanStupak Yeah me too. I posted it to the app's issues section - https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-apiport/issues/853